# Vue router keeps component alive after changing route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I've to routes `/home` and `/profile`

`/profile` route is supposed to be private can be accessed by authenticated users only

I'm using `firebase/auth` and route guard to achieve that

that's the router code

```
const router = new Router({
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: Home
},
{
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'profileSettings',
    component: ProfileSettings,
    beforeEnter: authGuard
},
{
    path: '/auth',
    name: 'auth',
    component: Auth
})

function authGuard(from, to, next) {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            next()
        } else {
            next('/auth')
        }
    })
}
```

logout code

```
logout() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    })
}
```

the template code to call logout function

```
<a href='#" @click.prevent="logout">Logout</a>
```

After I go to `/profile` then return to `/home` and logout redirect happens to `auth` page

Comment: if you are removing the state of the `user` on your logout method then according to your code it would always redirect to the `/auth` route. Need more code to make a better decision though.

Comment: @TJWeems I've added the code I use for logout.
I believe it does remove the state of the `user` but why should it always do the redirect and how to prevent it as I'm not in the `/profile` view?

Comment: well the `authGuard` function is what is redirecting you. it is checking that user exists, and if user does not exist redirect to the `/auth` page. If you dont want it to redirect just remove that logic, however I dont think that is what you want to do you may just need to modify the `if` statement. can you please show the template that is calling the `logout` method.

Comment: I know it's `authGuard` what is redirecting, but I'm using it to prevent unauthenticated users from entering `/profile` but the redirect happens also after I leave `/profile` and logout from `/home` view.
I've added the template code to the question

Comment: okay maybe I am not understanding your issue. The only other thing I can tell you is to use a `button` instead of the `a`. try this. `<button type="button" @click="logout">Logout</button>`. it will run your method without refreshing the page which maybe what is redirecting you.

Comment: Thank you but it didn't solve the issue.I think it's because the `/profile` view is kept alive and vue don't destroy it after change route to `/home`

Comment: okay well thats a different issue that has nothing to do with your routeGuard. perhaps you could provide a `:key="someConditionalVariable"` to template parent element of your profile view as a way to trick Vue into recreating the component but with out more context into your application I can only assume things. Hopefully you get it figured out!.